# Access violation at address at delphi dll

Tags: delphi

I get an error in my delphi ( XE 10 ) dll sometimes.

I get "Accesse violation at address" at setp 2.

> Step2 Accesse violation at address 0AC95985 in module … Read of
>   address FFFFFFFC, high(a)=31

My delphi dll

```
Library hash_sha256;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Hash,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

function MyHash(AKey, AData: PAnsiChar): Pchar; stdcall;
var
  a: TArray<byte>;
  i: integer;
  s: ShortString;
begin
  try
    s:='';
    Result:='';

    try
      a:=THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(String(AData), String(AKey));
    except
      on E : Exception do
         ShowMessage('Step1'+E.Message);
    end;


    try
      for i:=0 to high(a) do
        s:=s+PChar(inttohex(a[i],2));
    except
      on E : Exception do
        ShowMessage('Step2 '+E.Message+', high(a)='+IntToStr(high(a)));
    end;

    try
      Result:=Pchar(s+'');
    except
      on E : Exception do
        ShowMessage('Step3'+E.Message);
    end;

  except
    on E : Exception do
      begin
        Result:=Pchar(AnsiString(E.Message));
      end;
  end;
end;

exports MyHash name 'hash_sha256';

begin
end.
```

Who can help me ???

Comment: Do some debugging. Do you have any idea how to debug. What are you waiting for.  Learn to debug. If we were to help we'd need to see the complete program. Perhaps your calling program is wrong.

Comment: You should never return `PChar` or any structured type as a function result through a DLL. Pass it as a parameter instead, and return the success/failure of the function call.

Comment: Are you aware about Unicode stuff?

Comment: Indeed, you are passing in `PAnsiChar` types but returning a `PWideChar` type, considering you're using Delphi 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At step 2, you are trying to append a UnicodeString via a PWideChar to an Ansi ShortString.  FFFFFFFC is hex for -4, which implies the compiler is trying to access a leading string/array header via a nil pointer.

That is suspicious enough, but then at step 3 you are type-casting the ShortString to PWideChar, which is just plain wrong. You really need to stop mixing Ansi and Unicode together.

It is also wrong to return a pointer to a local variable in the first place. When the function exits, the variable is freed, leaving the pointer pointing at invalid memory.  A safer option is to make the caller pass in an allocated buffer that the function fills in as needed.

Try something more like this:

```
Library hash_sha256;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Hash,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

function MyHash(AKey, AData: PAnsiChar; OutStr: PChar; OutLen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  a: TArray<Byte>;
  i: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
  Result := 0;
  try
    try
      a := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(AnsiString(AData), AnsiString(AKey));
    except
      on E : Exception do begin
        E.Message := 'Step1 ' + E.Message;
        raise;
      end;
    end;

    try
      s := '';
      for i := Low(a) to High(a) do
        s := s + IntToHex(a[i], 2);
    except
      on E : Exception do begin
        E.Message := 'Step2 ' + E.Message + ', high(a)=' + IntToStr(High(a));
        raise;
      end;
    end;

    if OutStr <> nil then
    begin
      try
        StrPLCopy(OutStr, s, OutLen);
      except
        on E : Exception do begin
          E.Message := 'Step3 ' + E.Message;
          raise;
        end;
      end;    
      Result := min(Length(s), OutLen);
    end else
      Result := Length(s)+1;        
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;

exports
  MyHash name 'hash_sha256';

begin
end.
```

Comment: Get "Access violation at address 08307077 in ... Write of address 00000008"

Comment: @user6802100 at which step? An AV at address 00000008 still implies a nil pointer is being accessed. But there is no nil pointer in this code.

Comment: @user6802100 Perhaps you did not allocate space for the `OutStr` in your calling routine. Please show how you are calling `hash_sha256()`.

Comment: No, I get "Out Of Memory", "Access violation at address ... Write of address 00000008" and "invalid pointer operation" on step 2

Comment: @user6802100: The only possible way I can see step 2 producing those kind of errors is if your system is so low on available memory that even simple string concatenations cannot be allocated.  That is not a problem with the code itself.  Use the debugger to see what code is actually located at the first memory address reported in the AV error message. Which code is it?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't return a `PChar` (or `PAnsiChar`), especially not if that is a pointer to a local string. The string will be deleted at the end of the function and the `P(Ansi)Char` becomes invalid. Hence the AV.

Do this instead:

```
function MyHash(AKey, AData: PAnsiChar; AResult: PAnsiChar; AResultLen: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  s: AnsiString;
  i: Integer;
  a: TArray<Byte>;
begin

  ...

  for i := 0 to High(a) do
    s := s + AnsiString(IntToHex(a[i], 2));

  except
    Exit(False);
  end;

  StrLCopy(AResult, PAnsiChar(s), AResultLen);
  Exit(True); 
end;
```

And you use it like this:

```
var
  LargeBuffer: array[Word] of AnsiChar;
  // etc.
begin
  if MyHash(yourKey, yourData, @LargeBuffer[0], Length(LargeBuffer)) then
    ...
```

or, dynamically:

```
var
  LargeBuffer: array of AnsiChar;
  ...
begin
  SetLength(LargeBuffer, 65536);
  if MyHash(yourKey, yourData, @LargeBuffer[0], Length(LargeBuffer)) then
    ...
```

or using a string:

```
var
  a: AnsiString;
  ...
begin
  SetLength(a, High(Word));
  if MyHash(yourKey, yourData, PAnsiChar(a), Length(a)) then
  begin
    a := PAnsiChar(a); // Updates a to the proper length (internally uses StrLen).
    // Use a here.
```

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes i get broken result like 'S' instead '90B17767DA17FEB7DA34E6CA8930A2BE9159EB70369136EFE49992CF131FDFF7'

Comment: Hard to tell what is "broken" about it. I am merely telling you how to avoid the AV.

Comment: No, i get error agein ... "Accesse violation at address"

Comment: Then you probably didn't declare a suitably sized buffer at the user's site. See update.

Comment: @user6802100: Take a look at the updates I made, on how to use it: either with a fixed size buffer, a dynamically allocated buffer or with an `AnsiString` set to a large length and then pruned to the proper size.